# XSLT Multiple CDATA sections

Tags: xslt

I am a bit of a novice in XLST but I'm having an issue which has me tearing my hair out. I have an XML lookup file that looks like this....

```
<car make='honda'>
    <model>
        <![CDATA[I am a civic]]>
    </model>
    <model>
        <![CDATA[I am a CRV]]>
    </model>
</car>
```

Using an XSLT stylesheet I am passing my primary file then going to this lookup file and trying to display what is in the CDATA section.....

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('lookup.xml')/car[@make='honda']">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem I have is that the text in CDATA is being returned all together. For example this code currently produces...

```
<p>
I am a civic
I am a CRV
</p>
```

But I really want...

```
<p>I am a civic</p>
<p>I am a CRV</p>
```

Can anyone please help me with this one.

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('lookup.xml')/car[@make='honda']">
```

Do this instead....

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('lookup.xml')/car[@make='honda']/model">
```

This will iterate over the **model** elements individually, which is what you require.